# Alphabetically arranging character variable in R Markdown

Tags: r, dplyr

Working on a R markdown document, I've got a 1540 variable of characters (more precisely a variable of Names like "Carlos") and I'm interested in arranging it by alphabetical order. Is there anyway using packages as dplyr or doBy?

So far I've tried:

```
ID=LETTERS
library(dplyr)
 datos %>%
 arrange(datos$Nombre,ID) %>%
kable()
```

and

```
library(doBy)
orderBy(~ID, datos$Nombre)
```

But in both cases the problem is the vectors' size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with RMarkdown. You can use `dplyr::arrange`

I assume you want to reorder your whole dataframe, and not just one column.

```
datos %>%
  arrange(Nombre)
```

Comment: As easy as that, thank u so much. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Will you please mark the question as answered if this was sufficient